# MySQL Query Optimization without Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I am counting total login time for every user using this query:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `EventLog` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventType` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeZone` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGIN', '2014-04-27 09:00:04', 1,'GMT-7');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGIN', '2014-04-27 10:00:04', 1,'GMT-7');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGIN', '2014-04-27 10:00:04', 2,'GMT-6');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGOUT', '2014-04-27 09:49:04', 1,'GMT-7');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGOUT', '2014-04-27 10:30:04', 1,'GMT-7');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGOUT', '2014-04-27 10:30:04', 2,'GMT-6');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGIN', '2014-04-27 11:49:04', 3,'GMT-5');
INSERT INTO `EventLog` (`eventType`, `time`, `userId`,`timeZone`) VALUES ('LOGIN', '2014-04-27 08:30:04', 4,'GMT-2');
```

Query:

```
select userId,
sum(loginTimeInHour) as loginTimeInHour
from(
    select e1.userId, (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()),e1.time)))/(60*60) as loginTimeInHour from 
    EventLog e1
    left join EventLog e2
    on e1.userId = e2.userId
    and e2.eventType = 'LOGOUT'
    and e1.time < e2.time
    where e1.eventType = 'LOGIN'
    group by e1.id having min(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()) - e1.time)
) temp
group by userId;
```

[(fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e018f/1). Is it possible to get same results without using SubQuery. Actually I want to create mysql **view** and view does't suppose SubQuery. Any Options? Thanks in Advice

Comment: why do you need the outer query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbd7d/3

Comment: hi..Thanks for your response but, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dadd7/1 When user with userId login again, it will not give you right results.

Comment: Just to inform you: Your query is not correct. In your subquery you combine each login with all later logouts. Then you group by id. You select the user id found in the login record and randomly one of the time spans. This *can* be the time span from login to directly following logout, but doesn't have to. It can as well be any later logout. The dbms is free to choose, because you don't use any aggregating function here. (Most other dbms would not accept the query as syntactically correct. MySQL does.)

Comment: Moreover *having min(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()) - e1.time)* adds nothing to the query. It just checks if the minimum difference is zero (it's a boolean expression). The having clause is capable of removing an e1 (which you don't want anyhow), but as it is written, its condition is always met, so it doesn't do anything. (This handling of boolean values is another speciality of MySQL btw. The statement is invalid in other dbms.)

Comment: Hi, @ThorstenKettner, You are right. My Query is incorrect. Please go through this link http://bit.ly/1kkPtsU I posted this as question. Help me if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got answer,

```
SELECT e1.userid, SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COALESCE(e2.time, NOW())) - 
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e1.time))/3600 total 
FROM eventlog e1 
LEFT JOIN eventlog e2
  ON e1.userid = e2.userid AND e2.eventType='LOGOUT' AND e1.time < e2.time
LEFT JOIN eventlog e3
  ON e1.userid = e3.userid AND e1.time < e3.time AND e3.time < e2.time
WHERE e1.eventType='LOGIN' AND e3.time IS NULL
GROUP BY e1.userid
```

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid the subquery to get the same result:

```
select e1.userId,
sum((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()),e1.time)))/(60*60)) 
as loginTimeInHour from
EventLog e1
left join EventLog e2
on e1.userId = e2.userId
and e2.eventType = 'LOGOUT'
and e1.time < e2.time
 where e1.eventType = 'LOGIN'
group by e1.id having min(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()) - e1.time)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e018f/4)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response but see, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/770c0/2 When user with userId 2 logs in again, your query will give wrong results there.

Comment: sorry, it was user with userId 1.

Answer (score -1):

You could optimize your query by simply joining the tables this way:

```
select e1.userId, 
    sum((TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()), e1.time)))/(60*60)) as loginTimeInHour
from EventLog e1 left outer join EventLog e2 on
    (e1.userId = e2.userId and e1.time < coalesce(e2.time, NOW()))
    where e1.eventType = 'LOGIN' and coalesce(e2.eventType, 'LOGOUT') = 'LOGOUT'
group by e1.userId;
```

**Update:**

Since the query above summarizes all the variations of login-time / logout-time, it is not working for you.

To fulfill your requirements, the query would need double aggregation (e.g. sum(min())), which is not allowed by mysql. Such queries must be split into subqueries like the one you have in your question.

Unfortunately you cannot create a view that has subqueries in its `FROM` clause, so I suggest you to consider having your view keep a log of every login session with duration, and summarize them on retrieval, when you query the data from it:

```
select distinct e1.userId, 
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(coalesce(e2.time,NOW()), e1.time))/(60*60) as LoginTimeHour
from EventLog e1 left outer join EventLog e2 on
    (e1.userId = e2.userId and e1.time < coalesce(e2.time, NOW()))
    where e1.eventType = 'LOGIN' and coalesce(e2.eventType, 'LOGOUT') = 'LOGOUT'
group by  e1.userId, e1.time;
```

You could also consider extending your EventLog table with a `loggedInTime` field, which you fill from within a trigger, when a `LOGOUT` event gets logged (calculate on the spot the time spent logged in for the actual user).

This way you already have the time diffs to summarize for your view.

Comment: Hi @rekaszeru Thanks for your response. but see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/770c0/3 It's give wrong result for userId-1. User with userId 1 didn't logged in 2.8 hours actually.

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia, you're right, it does not work that way. You need a workaround for such a query, please see my update.

Comment: hi, @rekaszeru, I know that solution which you mentioned. I already satisfied my purpose by creating two views. One view for internal sub query. But my question was to remove that.. :( Thanks :)